# How to specify to validate this situation with generics?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to validate this class: `min >= max`. I realized using generics I can't use the comparators.

This is my generic class.

```
public class Range<T>
{
    public T MinValue { get; set; }
    public T MaxValue { get; set; }

    public Range() { }

    public Range(T min, T max)
    {
        this.MinValue = min;
        this.MaxValue = max;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;

        var other = obj as Range<T>;
        return this.MinValue.Equals(other.MinValue) &&
               this.MaxValue.Equals(other.MaxValue);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0},{1}", this.MinValue, this.MaxValue);
    }
}
```

T datatype can be only numbers, is there a way to accept just numbers and accept the `<=`?

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't constrain generics to numbers, but you can constrain `T` to `IComparable<T>` and then use `CompareTo()`

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    ....
}
```

Then you can say:

```
if (min.CompareTo(max) >= 0)...
```

And throw a validation exception or whatever validation you'd like.  You can use the same thing to make sure value is >= min and <= max.

```
if (value.CompareTo(min) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(max) <= 0)...
```

Comment: struct constraint wouldn't give access to >, <, etc.  In addition some things implement `IComparable<T>` but aren't `struct` such as `string`.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying adding it wouldn't gain anything since you'd lose ability to use it with `string`, it might be desirable to have a Range<string> from "A" to "Z" for example...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    ...

    public bool Check(T value)
    {
        return value.CompareTo(min) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(max) <= 0;
    }
}
```

If you range between 0 and 10, and want 0, 10 to fail (exclude min and max) - simply replace ">=" with ">" and "<=" with "<".

I would also recommend changing in the Equals override from:

```
return this.MinValue.Equals(other.MinValue) &&
       this.MaxValue.Equals(other.MaxValue);
```

to this:

```
return this.MinValue.CompareTo(other.MinValue) == 0 &&
       this.MaxValue.CompareTo(other.MaxValue) == 0;
```

Comment: Validating that max > min or max >= min is the same logic.